# Browser Caching - Why do I see repetitive http requests for javascript files if they are cached?

Tags: javascript, http, iis, internet-explorer-11, browser-cache

I am trying to improve performance of few web pages and wanted to understand if the javascript files are cached by I.E or not for my internal application. So, I had fiddler to watch the requests going to server.

I can see, **every single time a create customer page is loaded, the same number of requests in the fiddler, for the same files with Result '200' (and not 304 - not modified ) to fetch javascript files. These include jquery, knockout and a few custom ones.**

I studied the request and response header (below) but I see cache-control to be ok and nothing that conveys it is not cached. But don't understand why these same http requests show up in fiddler (which conveys a request is actually made to server) if it is cached.

I can see the same requests every time going to server, which makes me wonder :

1. Is the browser caching these or not ?
2. If not, are these atleast cached in IIS ?
3. How can I avoid these unnecessary http requests, since these javascript files dont change at all ?

[image]

Many Thanks.

Comment: I am guessing in the dev tools in your browser you have it set to never cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *request* for the file has a `Pragma: no-cache` header (up at the top of your image, two lines under "Request Headers"), which tells the browser and the server that you [don't want to use the cached copy](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.32).

You'll want to look at how you're making that request to find out why that header is there, and get rid of it.

Possibilities:

- You're loading it via some kind of AMD or other dynamic loading mechanism that is configured to not use cache
- You're running with development tools with the "disable cache" option most of them have turned on

Comment: Yes that was spot on. My bad, I had I.E dev tools opened when I did my profiling and that's the reason for the no cache headers. Thanks a lot.